# Acquire the earlist lock among multiple locks

Tags: python, multithreading

Say I have two locks (e.g. one waiting for http response, one waiting for user interrupt). How do I wait until *either* lock is released?

```py
from threading import Lock

def f(a: Lock, b: Lock, /):
    with as_completed(a, b) as x:
        ...
```

Does python provide an `as_completed` function as examplified above?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? If you want code to await either one of two different events (whichever happens first), then maybe "lock" is not a very good word to describe what it's awaiting, and maybe `threading.Lock` is not the right tool for the job. Maybe an [`Event` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) would serve you better?

Comment: @SolomonSlow You raised a good point. `event` and `condition` suits my need better.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit a function that waits on each lock to a `concurrent.futures.Executor`, and then use `concurrent.futures.as_completed` to wait for whichever future completes first. Something like:

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time

from threading import Thread, Lock

l1 = Lock()
l2 = Lock()


class Locker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, lock, **kwargs):
        self.lock = lock
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def run(self):
        with self.lock:
            sleeptime = random.randint(10, 30)
            print(f"{self.name} sleeping for {sleeptime} seconds")
            time.sleep(random.randint(10, 30))


def wait_for(name, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    return (name, lock)


lockers = [Locker(l1, name="l1"), Locker(l2, name="l2")]
for task in lockers:
    task.start()

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
waiters = [pool.submit(wait_for, "l1", l1), pool.submit(wait_for, "l2", l2)]
for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(waiters):
    name, lock = task.result()
    print(f"lock {name} unlocked first")
    break

# ...do some stuff here...

# wait for remaining threads to complete
for task in lockers:
    print(f'waiting on {task.name}')
    task.join()
```